Tensor chain rule
Say if there is a function $f$ that maps a real number $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (some parameter) to a tensor $\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times256\times256}$ (some rgb image data). Then there is another function $L$ (some loss function) that maps $\mathbb{y}\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times256\times256}$ to another scaler $l\in\mathbb{R}$.
I never know anything about tensor calculus, but from intuition, if I want to compute $dl/dx$, the formula should be like a form of chain rule, which is:
$$
\frac{dl}{dx}=\frac{dl}{d\mathbf{y}}\triangle\frac{d\mathbf{y}}{dx}
$$
I use "$\triangle$" here because I have no idea which "product" should be applied here. I do know that $dl/d\mathbf{y}$ should be a tensor with the same shape as $\mathbf{y}$, so as $d\mathbb{y}/dx$ (i.e. $dl/d\mathbf{y}_{ijk}$ and $d\mathbf{y}_{ijk}/dx$) so "$\triangle$" must be some "tensor product" here, and for its result, it should be a scalar ($dl/dx$ is scalar).
What tensor product gives a salar as output as $\triangle$ does here?

$
\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$The general approach to calculating the gradient of a tensor function $(F)$ is to first calculate the differential of the function, then transform it into a gradient by rearranging the differential expression until it is in the following form
$$\eqalign{
dF_{\c{ijk}} &= \sum_p\sum_q\sum_r\sum_s G_{\c{ijk}\,pqrs}\;dX_{pqrs} \\
}$$
where the free index grouping $\{ijk\}$ appears in the same order
on $\{F,G\}$ while the summed (aka dummy) index grouping $\{pqrs\}$
must appear with the same ordering on $\{G,dX\}$
The tensor $G$ is identified as the gradient
of $F$ with respect to $X$
$$\eqalign{
G_{ijk\,pqrs} = \grad{F_{ijk}}{X_{pqrs}} \\
}$$

Your particular problem involves two scalars $\{l,x\}$
and a third-order tensor $\{Y\}$
$$\eqalign{
\def\Y{Y_{pqr}}
d\Y &= \gradLR{\Y}x dx \\
dl &= {\large\sum_p\sum_q\sum_r}\gradLR{l}{\Y} d\Y \\
&= {\large\sum_p\sum_q\sum_r}\gradLR{l}{\Y} \gradLR{\Y}x dx \\
\grad lx &= {\large\sum_p\sum_q\sum_r}\gradLR{l}{\Y} \gradLR{\Y}x \\
}$$
and the mysterious $\Delta$ product is actually the triple contraction (aka triple-dot) product.
NB: I used a simplified notation above (which seems sufficient for the application you described), but for general tensors you'll need to distinguish covariant and contravariant indices in the contraction products.

Thanks for the reply! This solves my confusion.
A simple follow up quesion: would you recommend any beginner friendly textbook/material for learning tensor calculus?

Rather than Tensor Calculus  you should probably look for materials pertaining to Matrix Calculus since the former requires mastering concepts (e.g. metric tensors, contravariant/covariant components, etc) which are not necessary for most fields (e.g. machine learning or numerical optimization).  The standard text is probably Magnus and Neudecker's Matrix Differential Calculus
For looking up formulas, try the
Matrix Cookbook
or
Bernstein's Matrix Mathematics: Theory, Facts, and Formulas

thanks a lot for your advice
